# Zen Cart Custom Template Problem

Tags: php, zen-cart

I have been asked to upload a Zen Cart site to my servers and have done so fine.

I am getting a problem now with the fact that the client has uploaded his custom template into the includes/templates folder and selected it in the admin - but it still wont load it. instead it just loads the template_default style.

I am been through every document I can find and have performed the 'reset' of the Layout Boxes Controller, but nothing seems to resolve it.

Can anyone tell me if there's a file I need to tweak or something to make sure it loads my custom style?

Cheers,

C.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to overwrite the default theme with yours.  I know this is not what you are asking, however, it would solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Zen Cart templates can be really simple or really complex.  So installing them can be easy or complicated.  The files are probably in the wrong place, or not completely installed.  It's easy to make a mistake.  Just in case, here's the outline:

1a. Simple - Copy the cart template files to includes/templates/your_template_name/.

or

1b. complex - Copy the cart template folders to includes/.

2 Go to Admin > Tools > Template Selection and click Edit.
Select your_template_name.  (If you don't see your_template_name something has gone wrong.)

3 Many templates install with the sideboxes turned off.  Go to Admin > Tools > Layout Boxes Controller and edit the sideboxes to turn them on.

One idea for trouble-shooting ...
Look at the database template_select table.  What template_dir is set?

Answer (score 0):

If this is happening, double check the file includes/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/template_info.php.  This file is used by the system to determine if a folder under includes/templates is actually a template, and things won't work without this file.  Once you've set this file up, go back to admin->tools->template selection and try re-selecting your custom template.